# Two instances of a class: only sort 1

Tags: c#, arrays, interface, icomparable

I have a basic class that has four attributes (`Patient`).  In `Main()` I have reserved the memory for the array and before I actually create the instance, I ask the user for the account number to ensure it doesn't already exist within the array.  So `BinarySearch` requires it to be sorted but as soon as I sort it the ability to do the `for` loop is lost.

```
//Variables
int intMaxNum = 5; //set max number of patients to 5
int intInputValue;
int intResult;
string strTempName;
int intTempAge;
double dblTempTotal;

Patient[] objectPatient = new Patient[intMaxNum]; //create an array of references

for (int x = 0; x < objectPatient.Length; ++x)
{
   //attempt to create a 'shadow' class to search through and keep integrity of main class (objectPatient)
   Patient[] tempobjectPatient = new Patient[intMaxNum];
   tempobjectPatient = objectPatient;
   if (x > 0)
   {

      Console.Write("\n***Next Patient***");

      Array.Sort(tempobjectPatient); //this will sort both objects even though I send the temporary class only - interface impact I'm sure
   }

   //ask for the Patient Account number
   Console.Write("\nEnter Patient Account Number: ");
   ReadTheAccountNumber:
   intInputValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   //create temporary class for comparison
   Patient SeekPatient = new Patient();
   SeekPatient.PatientNumber=intInputValue; // reset the default info with the input Pateint Account Number

   //verify the Patient Account number doesn't already exist
   intResult = Array.BinarySearch(tempobjectPatient, SeekPatient);
   //intResult = Array.BinarySearch(objectPatient, SeekPatient);

   //if (objectPatient.Equals(SeekPatient)) //Can not get the .Equals to work at all...
   if (intResult >= 0)
   {
      Console.Write("\nSorry, Patient Account Number {0} is a duplicate.", intInputValue);
      Console.Write("\nPlease re-enter the Patient Account Number: ");
      goto ReadTheAccountNumber;
   }
   else //no match found, get the rest of the data and create the object
   {
      if (x > 0) { Console.Write("***Patient Account Number unique and accepted***\n"); } //looks silly to display this if entering the first record
      Console.Write("Enter the Patient Name: ");
      strTempName = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("Enter the Patient Age: ");
      intTempAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.Write("Enter the total annual Patient amount due: ");
      dblTempTotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
      objectPatient[x] = new Patient(intInputValue, strTempName, intTempAge, dblTempTotal);
   }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class Patient : IComparable
{
    //Data fields
    private int patientNumber;
    private string patientName;
    private int patientAge;
    private double patientAmountDue;

    //Constructors
    public Patient(): this(9,"ZZZ",0,0.00)
    {
    }
    public Patient(int _patientNumber, string _patientName, int _patientAge, double _patientAmountDue)
    {
       PatientNumber = _patientNumber;
       PatientName = _patientName;
       PatientAge = _patientAge;
       PatientAmountDue = _patientAmountDue;
    }
    //Properties
    public int PatientNumber
    { 
       get { return patientNumber; }
       set { patientNumber = value; }
    }
    public string PatientName
    {
       get { return patientName; }
       set { patientName = value; }
    }
    public int PatientAge
    {
       get { return patientAge; }
       set { patientAge = value; }
    }
    public double PatientAmountDue
    {
       get { return patientAmountDue; }
       set { patientAmountDue = value; }
    }

    //Interfaces
    int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
    {
       int returnVal; //temporary value container

       Patient temp = (Patient)o; //create temp instance of the class
       if (this.PatientNumber > temp.PatientNumber)
          returnVal = 1;
       else
          if (this.PatientNumber < temp.PatientNumber)
             returnVal = -1;
          else
             returnVal = 0; //exact match
       return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `goto`.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Please don't start the goto debate! :-)

Comment: what debate, even if you think using goto is fine, it is used totally wrong here

Comment: Does C# allow using goto?

Comment: Also please call them properties, attributes are something completely different

Comment: Variable tempobjectPatient  makes no sense. You are not copiing arrays, but having the same array in both variables. For better understanding what is happening, execute your sample step by step checking variables each step. As a step to simplify sample - use Dictionary instead of sorting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
Patient[] tempobjectPatient = new Patient[intMaxNum];
```

creates a new array and assigns it to `tempobjectPatient`. But this new array is never used, because here

```
tempobjectPatient = objectPatient;
```

you immediately assign the old one to `tempobjectPatient`. So after this, you don't have two array instances. Both `tempobjectPatient` and `objectPatient` refer to the same instance.

You probably want:

```
Patient[] tempobjectPatient = (Patient[])objectPatient.Clone();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for...missing the cloning.  Some of the other responses are good but taking away from my intention of learning the sorting and interface functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the *patient numbers* into `HashSet<int>` and test via `Contains()` if a number is allocated one:

```
class Patient : IComparable { 
  ...
  // Simplest, not thread safe
  private static HashSet<int> s_AllocatedPatientNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

  public static Boolean IsNumberAllocated(int patientNumber) {
    return s_AllocatedPatientNumbers.Contains(patientNumber);
  } 

  public int PatientNumber { 
    get { 
      return patientNumber; 
    }
    set { 
      s_AllocatedPatientNumbers.Remove(patientNumber);
      patientNumber = value; 
      s_AllocatedPatientNumbers.Add(patientNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

So whenever you need to test if the number has been allocated you have no need to *create a temporal patient*, *sort the arra*y etc. just one simple call:

```
  if (Patient.IsNumberAllocated(intInputValue)) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: This seems like a great result as well.  Several pieces in here I have not learned yet so I was trying to get my head around it.  The option of just cloning my array's was what I was missing...from Henrik.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Array with a Dictionary, it is desigend to be used with unique keys:

```
Dictionary<int,Patient> patients = new Dictionary<int,Patient>();

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter Patient Account Number: ");
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (patients.ContainsKey(number))
    {
        Console.Write("\nSorry, Patient Account Number {0} is a duplicate.", number);
        Console.Write("\nPlease re-enter the Patient Account Number: ");
        continue;
    }

    Console.Write("***Patient Account Number unique and accepted***\n");
    Console.Write("Enter the Patient Name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter the Patient Age: ");
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter the total annual Patient amount due: ");
    double amountDue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    patients.Add(number, new Patient(number, name, age, amountDue));
}
```

The loop is now missing an exit condition.

EDIT:
While this does not answer the question of the title i think it is what the OP was looking for.